# In Software & Updates, Update tab, 'When there are other updates' option is grayed out

Tags: update-manager

In Software & Updates (software-properties-gtk) Update tab 'When there are other updates' option is grayed out. No options available. I want to choose 'Display immediately'.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Run `sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` and try again.

Comment: @kulfi nothing happened.

Comment: You could try reinstalling the `software-properties-gtk` by running `sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-common` and see if the setting comes back.  There might be a chance that this is a bug in the app as the setting I believe is embedded in the `software-properties-gtk` app itself.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue on my minimal Xubuntu install. After installing `update-notifier` I was able to change that setting.

`$ sudo apt install update-notifier`

Comment: This worked on Xubuntu 22.04. I was then able to choose "Display immediately".

Comment: I ran into this on Ubuntu 22.04, and this fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the '**When there are other updates**' option is greyed out if the '**Automatically check for updates**' option is set to '*never*'.

If you change the value '*never*' to e.g. '*Daily*', the '**When there are other updates**' option stays greyed out until you close and reopen the '**Software & Updates**' Window, so that the previously chosen value is properly saved.

This time the '**When there are other updates**' options should  be selectable and you can set it for instance to '*Display immediately*'.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 64-Bit Desktop.